# I have a Java String, i need to extract only the first digits from it. for example the String: "2 fishes 3" I want to get only: "2"

Tags: java, android, regex, string

For example the `String`: "123 fishes 224"

I want to get only: "123"

I have these lines of code:

```
String num1 = mEtfirst.getText().toString(); 
num1 = num1.replaceAll("[^0-9.,]+","");
```

the code above accepts the two numbers which are 123 and 224 in "123 fishes 224". What I wish to achieve is to only accept or extract "123" and place it to num1. Is it possible?

Comment: that returns you a string with just numbers, all you have to do it get the first character of the string

Comment: @tyczj
what if the string is "123 fishes 222"
how could i get "123" automatically if i only get the first character of the string?

Comment: then instead of replacing non character with `""` replace it with come character like a `,` or something then do a string `split` on that character and you will get an array of numbers and you just use the first index

Comment: regex, find (\d+), take the first group, voila.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :)

```
String num1 = mEtfirst.getText().toString(); 
char[] temp = num1.toCharArray();
int i=0;
num1="";

while(Character.isDigit(temp[i]))
     num1=num1+Character.toString(temp[i++]);
```

This converts the string to a character array, checks the array character by character, and stores it in num1 until a non-digit character is encountered.

Edit:

Also, if you want to convert num1 to an integer, use:

```
num1=Integer.parseInt(num1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
        String testStr = "123asdkfjradical9999";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testStr);
        if(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); //This is the value that you want
        }
     }
}
```